# Weird shadow stripes in workbench - glitch

Tags: shadows, workbench-render-engine

I think this should be considered a bug.

If you take a look at the screenshot, you'll see dark stripes going across the viewport. They only appear with shadows enabled in Workbench.

The level of glitch depends on how closely I'm looking at geometry. I can sometimes reduce it by setting near and far clipping planes, but it's a game of guess and I can never actually remove it.
The glitch is more prominent if I turn on backface culling.

Can I get rid of the glitch anyhow?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A) Do you have any geometry parented to the camera? B) what is your system and graphics card information?

Comment: might be your graphic card. I opened your file and didn't have such problems. No glitch at all.

Comment: I think I don't have anything parented to anything (esp. camera) in the model. But I'm not really advanced in Blender so if you could help me check.

Comment: My specs are: system: Windows 10, CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600, GPU: GTX 1070.